# adding a field to the new order customer select grid

Tags: magento2.3, grid, backend

I want to add the company name to the grid for when you make a new order in the backend and have to select the customer you make the order from.

Only i can find nothing on how to add anything to this grid as it is not commenly edited.

I would like to know how to add a field to this grid but dont know how to.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need add a new attribute, 'company_name', to customer_entity.

Then create a new Module, 'Jeff_Test' and enable it.

1) Create a ui_component file under the module at *app/code/Jeff/Test/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml*

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="company_name" class="Jeff\Test\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CompanyName">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Company Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

2) generate the Ui component class at *app/code/Jeff/Test/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/CompanyName*

```
<?php
namespace Jeff\Test\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;

class CompanyName extends Column
{

    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;
    protected $_customerfactory;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
        CustomFactory $customFactory,
        array $components = [], array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        $this->_customerfactory = $customFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                //$order_id = $order->getEntityId();
                $email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
                $collection = $this->_customfactory->create()->getCollection();
                $collection->addFieldToFilter('email',$email);
                $data = $collection->getFirstItem();
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $data->getCompanyName();
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

3) Define a Plugin for sales order grid, at *app/code/Jeff/Test/etc/adminhtml/di.xml*

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Reporting">
        <plugin name="sales_grid_collection" type="\Jeff\Test\Model\Plugin\Sales\Order\Grid"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

4) Create the plugin class, at *app\code\Jeff\Test\Model\Plugin\Sales\Order*

```
<?php
namespace Jeff\Test\Model\Plugin\Sales\Order;
class Grid
{
    public static $table = 'sales_order_grid';
    public static $leftJoinTable = 'customer_entity';

    public function afterSearch($object, $collection)
    {
        if ($collection->getMainTable() === $collection->getConnection()->getTableName(self::$table)) {

            $leftJoinTableName = $collection->getConnection()->getTableName(self::$leftJoinTable);

            $collection
            ->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                ['ce'=>$leftJoinTableName], //ce ==> cutomer_entity
                "ce.email = main_table.customer_email",
                [
                    'company_name' => 'ce.company_name'
                ]
            );

            $where = $collection->getSelect()->getPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);

            $collection->getSelect()->setPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE, $where);

        }
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE: How to add company_name to customer_entity.** 
Create a file 'InstallData.php' in your Module (app/code/Jeff/Test/Setup/InstallData.php):

```
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, Config $eavConfig)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'company_name',
            [
                'type'         => 'static',
                'label'        => 'Company Name',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'required'     => false,
                'visible'      => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'position'     => 999,
                'system'       => 0,
            ]
        );
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'company_name');


        $attribute->setData(
           'used_in_forms',
           ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address']

        );

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: you say to add company name to the customer entity, can you give some more details on this as i am not that familiar with what you are talking about

Comment: Hi Sprite, I updated the original post by adding InstallData.php content.

Comment: it seems that this answer is for the sales order gird, while i asked for the sales order create customer grid